# Recursive graph expansion and rewiring

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I want to take this graph

[image]

and convert it into this graph

[image]

by repeatedly substituting each of its nodes according to this rule

[image]

After loading the initial graph and the substitution rule

```
ic = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 1 <-> 4, 3 <-> 2, 3 <-> 4, 4 <-> 2}, 
  GraphLayout -> "RadialDrawing"]
```

[image]

I tried fiddling with NestGraph

```
NestGraph[substitution, ic, 1, DirectedEdges -> False]
```

and got this:

[image]

How can I programmatically specify the proper rewiring?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have used the functions `EdgeDelete` and `EdgeAdd` to expand the graph.
The code generates new vertex names by incrementing the largest vertex name in the graph.

```
nextVertexNames[g_] := Max[VertexList[g]] + {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}
replaceTripod[g_, v_] := Module[{
   oldNeighbors = DeleteCases[VertexComponent[g, v, 1], v], 
   newNeighbors = nextVertexNames[g], go = g
   },
  EdgeAdd[
   EdgeDelete[go, v <-> _],
   Flatten@{
     UndirectedEdge[v, #] & /@ First[newNeighbors],
     UndirectedEdge @@@ Partition[Riffle @@ newNeighbors, {2}, 1, 1],
     UndirectedEdge @@@ Thread[{Last@newNeighbors, oldNeighbors}]}
   ]
  ]
replaceTripods[g_] := 
  Fold[replaceTripod, g, 
   Extract[VertexList[g], Position[VertexDegree[g], 3]]];
```

For your case, use `replaceTripods[g]` to replace all tripods in the graph `g`.

**Update**
As kindly suggested by *halmir* below, the resulting graph can be displayed just as in your example using the option `GraphLayout -> "TutteEmbedding"`.

```
g = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 1 <-> 4, 2 <-> 3, 2 <-> 4, 3 <-> 4}, 
   VertexLabels -> "Name", GraphLayout -> "TutteEmbedding"];
replaceTripods[g]
```

[image]

Comment: I can see your answer produced the solution by using GraphLayout -> "TutteEmbedding"

Answer (score 2):

This may or may not do what you want. I don't know about making the layout nice, I'm afraid. The function `newvertex` returns `n` names which are not used as a vertex in the graph. Then `expandVertex` takes a vertex name and expands about that vertex in the manner stated. Alternatively, supply a list of names to have the expansion done on each in turn, or supply no names at all to have every valid vertex expanded in that way.

```
newvertex[g_, n_] := Max@VertexList[g] + Range[n]

expandVertex[g_, v_] /; VertexDegree[g, v] != 3 := g

expandVertex[g_, v_] := 
 With[{new = newvertex[g, 6]}, 
  With[{r = new[[1]], s = new[[2]], t = new[[3]], st = new[[4]], 
        rs = new[[5]], rt = new[[6]]}, 
   EdgeList[g] /. 
    {xx___, a_ <-> v | v <-> a_, yy___, b_ <-> v | v <-> b_, 
     zz___, d_ <-> v | v <-> d_, aa___}
    :>
   {xx, yy, zz, aa, 
    a <-> r, b <-> s, d <-> t, t <-> st, s <-> st, r <-> rs, 
    s <-> rs, r <-> rt, t <-> rt, rt <-> v, st <-> v, rs <-> v}]] 
// Graph[VertexList[g], #, VertexLabels -> "Name", GraphLayout -> "PlanarEmbedding"] &

expandVertex[g_, v_List] := Fold[expandVertex[#1, #2] &, g, v]

expandVertex[g_] := expandVertex[g, VertexList[g]]
```

Your example would be `expandVertex[ic]`.

It works by a very inefficient pattern match, checking that the input is a vertex of degree 3 and then constructing the appropriate edges.

This relies on the vertex names of the graph being integers (or, I suppose, real numbers), I'm afraid. It can be a real pain to work with arbitrary vertex names.